# incompatibility between gulp-clean-css, gulp-ruby-sass and gulp-sourcemaps

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have this task defined in my gulpfile.js:

```
var sass     = require('gulp-ruby-sass');
var cleanCss = require('gulp-clean-css');
var srcmaps  = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('css',function(){
    return  sass('css/**/*.scss',{sourcemap: true})
            .on('error',sass.logError)
            .pipe(srcmaps.write())
            .pipe(cleanCss())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});
```

The final output it's right, except for the fact that the source map generated doesn't seem to work (tested in firefox, the inspector always points to line 1, since the css is minified).

I tried adding `pipe(srcmaps.init())` before `pipe(cleanCss)` but it didn't work either. 
Removing the cleanCss line solved the problem (The source map worked fine), but the css won't get minified.

What am I missing?

Update: The cleanCss debug output is the following:

```
liquidacion.css: 7797
liquidacion.css: 1200
baja_cajas.css: 9918
baja_cajas.css: 2071
caja.css: 13160
caja.css: 2605
main.css: 11935
main.css: 2394
posiciones.css: 12905
posiciones.css: 2625
solicitud.css: 16182
solicitud.css: 3305
traslados.css: 12047
traslados.css: 2646
empleo.css: 19207
empleo.css: 3816
ingresos.css: 13832
ingresos.css: 2985
rq_personal.css: 17155
rq_personal.css: 3882
```

I already tried adding srcmaps.init() before cleanCss (and after sass), but it didn't work either.

Comment: what does  `.pipe(cleanCSS({debug: true}, function(details) {
            console.log(details.name + ': ' + details.stats.originalSize);
            console.log(details.name + ': ' + details.stats.minifiedSize);
        }))`  say?

Comment: I opened an issue with gulp-srcmaps the other day. It doesn't generate them correctly and so they don't work properly. https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps/issues/204 This seems to be a known issue.

Comment: I see, the weird thing is that it actually works (or it seems to) when I omit cleanCss.

Comment: Try adding `.pipe(sourcemaps.init())` to your `css` task

Comment: @Mills already tried, it didn't work either. Added the debug output to the question.

Comment: @Sebastianb hmm, if all else fails try using this as a reference, `cssnano` might be an alternative that could work for you https://github.com/zellwk/gulp-starter-csstricks/blob/master/gulpfile.js#L9

Comment: @Mills Thanks! I'll give it a try!

Comment: @Sebastianb https://github.com/ben-eb/gulp-cssnano#source-maps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115243/discussion-between-mills-and-sebastianb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally ended up replacing gulp-ruby-sass with gulp-sass, and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

`gulp-sourcemaps` only records transformations to your CSS up until `srcmaps.write()`. Once `srcmaps.write()` is called the source maps are written to the stream and any subsequent transformations will not be reflected in your source maps.

That means you need to run `cleanCss()` before `srcmaps.write()` if you want the minification to be reflected in your source maps:

```
gulp.task('css',function(){
  return  sass('css/**/*.scss',{sourcemap: true})
        .on('error',sass.logError)
        .pipe(cleanCss())
        .pipe(srcmaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});
```

Comment: Then you're doing something else wrong. I made a [sample app](https://github.com/svenschoenung/gulp-ruby-sass-sourcemaps-example) and the above code definitely works.

Comment: That's weird, maybe the node version has something to do? (I'm running 0.10.36). Anyway, I ended up replacing gulp-ruby-sass by gulp-sass and everything works now. Thanks for the help!